# Having multiple unity scenes open simultaneously

Tags: unity-game-engine, scene, simultaneous

I've been developing a board-style game in Unity3D. The main scene is the board, and has the data about each player and the current (randomly-generated) board stored within it.

I intend to add minigames into the game, for example when landing on a particular space on the board. Naturally, I would like to code the minigame in a separate scene. Is there a way I can do this without losing the instance of the current scene, so that the current scene's state is maintained?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: no, but there may be another way to do what you want.

A basic call to [`Application.LoadLevel`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application.LoadLevel.html) call will destroy the current scene before loading the next one. This isn't what you want.

If your minigame is relatively simple, you could use [`Instantiate`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Instantiate.html) to bring in a prefab and spawn it far away from the rest of your scene. You can even use scripts to switch to another camera, toggle player controls and other interactions in the scene, and so on. Once the minigame is done, you can destroy or disable whatever you brought in, and re-enable whatever needs to be turned on in the main scene.

You could create a separate scene and call [`Application.LoadLevelAdditive`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application.LoadLevelAdditive.html) to load that scene *without* destroying the current one. As above, you can then use scripts to manage which cameras and scene behaviors are active.

If you're careful, you don't really need two separate scenes. It may be enough to "fake" a scene switch.

Comment: Thanks rutter, I'll have a look at that when I get home and let you know :)

Comment: Now that `Application.LoadLevelAdditive` is obsolete use `SceneManager.LoadScene("SceneName",LoadSceneMode.Additive);` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Hard to give a complete answer without code, but you should look into the following things either with the unity documentation or youtube:

- PlayerPrefs, this is one way of saving data, although i believe it isn't entirely secure i.e. being able to edit from a text file.
- Serializable, this is apparently better than playerprefs.
- DonDestroyOnLoad, can carry over information to multiple scenes.
- Static variables, again not sure if this will help your particular problem.